# How can I create a launcher item for jvisualvm?

Tags: unity, launcher

When I create a launcher item for jvisualvm according to the regular procedure [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand), it does not behave as expected. Instead of just starting the app, it starts the app as a *different* item... What's going on???

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download and install Oracle JDK 1.7.0 in ~/jdk1.7.0 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Create a visualvm.desktop file according to the regular procedure, set the executable to be ~/jdk1.7.0/bin/jvisualvm
3. Drag the visualvm.desktop file onto the launcher
4. Start the app via the new launcher

Expected:

- VisualVM starts as a regular app

What actually happens:

- VisualVM does start up, but it manifests as a new, *different* item in the launcher instead of the one I just created
- This new item has a nice icon, so I try to keep it instead of the old one by checking "Keep In Launcher", however, when I click on this new item, nothing happens???

So my question is this: how can I create a well-behaved item in the launcher for jvisualvm?

Comment: have you actually installed JDK1.7 correctly?  run `java --version`

Comment: please post the contents of your `.desktop` file

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with many JAVA applications, the [BAMF framework](https://launchpad.net/bamf) (that is responsible for matching windows to their desktop files) fails in these cases. See this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bamf/+bug/757991

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a documented bug at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/visualvm/+bug/657048?comments=all

The /usr/bin/jvisualvm startup script (around line 13) is looking for: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk :
sv@ubu:~$ grep -n /usr/lib/jvm /usr/bin/jvisualvm
13:for j in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun; do

And, assuming the openjdk-6-jdk package is already installed (sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk), there is no link in /usr/lib/jvm for /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk:
sv@ubu:~$ ls /usr/lib/jvm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64  java-6-openjdk-amd64  java-6-openjdk-common

## Here's what worked for us:

So, to match things up and make the program work, simply create a symlink:
sv@ubu:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk

Note: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit version, so you may have to adjust your symlink accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the answer from [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash). It is an application which allows you to add no-native applications to the panel.