# How do I add an application to the dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I just installed Oneiric Ocelot, and I can't figure out how to add an application, which is stored in my home directory, to the dash. I can create a launcher, but I want it in the dash also.

Comment: @jokerdino: Thank you, seems to be a good solution. However, there surely also must be a way without installing new software?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

One way I use is to add an entry in the menu's with [alacarte](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/alacarte) package.

1. Install alacarte if it isn't already: `sudo apt-get install alacarte`
2. Open alacarte by typing it into the run prompt (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)
3. Click New item and fill in name and command.
4. Click OK and close alacarte.
5. Application should appear in the dash search.

Works on Unity and GNOME Shell (Ubuntu 17.10 and above).

Comment: In Ubuntu 13 you can go into alacarte and add the new item.  After you create it, it will look like nothing happened.  Then go to ~/.local/share/applications and you should see a file alacarte-made.desktop.  Right click on the file and go to properties then add the bottom of the properties window check the box to allow it to execute.  After you do that the item should show up in your dash.

Comment: @James ' solution works.

Comment: Works on 16.04 LTS

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 133):

There are 2 ways to go about this

## No new software method

**For 11.10 and newer**:

To create a simple custom `.desktop` you will need to add these entries to a `.desktop` file of your choice in ~/.local/share/applications/

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/your_application_name.desktop
```

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=the name you want shown
Comment=
Exec=command to run
Icon=icon name
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

For extra options for your .desktop file you can [visit this](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/?q=node/377) site. All the options available are very well described there.

You can also copy a existing application's .desktop file from `/usr/share/applications/`to your `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit it to fit your needs.

ie: this will copy gedit .desktop file to the folder where the .desktop files should be saved for a user

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop .
```

After that open that location using `nautilus ~/.local/share/applications/` and drag n drop the file you have just created to the Unity launcher.

Has an option instead of drag n dropping the file you can open dconf-editor (install it with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` or look for it in the USC) and navigate to `desktop.unity.launcher` and edit the key favorites by double clicking on the entries to the right of the key.

To add your custom launcher add it at the position you want with this format '/home//.local/share/applications/.desktop'. Don't forget to respect the `,` and the spaces in that line and make sure that the line starts and ends with `[` and `]`respectively.

With this method you will need to log off and back in for the change in favorites to take effect. This will make it appear in the dash

---

## Using New software

### Using `gnome-desktop-item-edit`

For this you need `gnome-tweak-tool` or `gnome-shell` installed

Use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

This will open the dialog Create Launcher

[image: Create Launcher]

You can put this `.desktop` file in `/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/` to make it appear in the dash

### Using `alacarte`

For this method, you need `alacarte` installed.Do it by

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

And use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `alacarte`

You will get this dialog:

[image]

Select the category you want and click "New Item"

You will get this dialog

[image: Create launcher-alacarte]

Click OK . It will appear in the dash

> **NOTE for Ubuntu 13.04 and above**:
>   After performing the above steps, nothing will happen and it will seem like nothing is added to the dash
>
> To resolve this, go to `~/.local/share/applications` and you should be able to see a file named `alacarte-made.desktop`.
>
> Right Click on this file and check the box which allows it `excecute` permissions.
>
> After closing the properties dialog, your entry will now appear in the dash.

---

*Sources:*

[Bruno Pereira's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78960/17722)

[Binarylife's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78968/17722)

[Kikixx's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/67781/17722)

[James' comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash/112812?noredirect=1#comment491682_67781)

Comment: alacart does not work in ubuntu 13.04. nothing appears in the dash after adding an item.

Comment: @waspinator Indeed. Luckily, the 'No new software method For 11.10 and newer' still works like a charm! (Done this using 13.10)

Comment: I appreciate your "No software" method.  (works on 15.04)

Comment: To appear in dash application results, just add **`NoDisplay=false`** at the end of the `.desktop` file and tada! [(source)](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-edit-dash-application-results)

Comment: To generate the `.desktop` file from a running application right-click the icon in the Launcher and select "Add to Dash". Then you can modify the generated file in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: @absynce `Add to Dash` doesn't appear for the app here. Why could that be?

Comment: One thing to note is that the target application of the `Exec=` line needs to be actually installed for the `.desktop` to show up in the Dash.  This one caught me out after a reinstall.

Comment: Don't forget to install new app: desktop-file-install <your_file.desktop>

Comment: Nautilus Actions seems to be dead.

Answer (score 11):

A .desktop file in `.local/share/applications` folder will also do the trick.

Just add the required `.desktop` files, make them executable using `chmod +x <filename>` and restart unity by typing `unity --replace`

A .desktop file for sublime text

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sublime Text 2
Comment=Launch Sublime Text 2
Icon=/home/user/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
Exec="/home/user/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Developer;Accessories;Accessibility;
StartupNotify=true
```

**Note**
If Exec string contains space characters, double quotes should be used.

Comment: `chmod +x <filename>` is not needed for dash. It is only required for `.desktop` files you want to run by double-clicking them. Useful for the ones in `~/Desktop`, but not useful in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: Is this answer true? I've got lots of .desktop files in .local/share/applications, and only some of them appear in the dash, presumably those specified in dconf-editor (launcher).

Comment: Yes, it should still work. Check if any of them have a NoDisplay=true. Try adding NoDisplay=false if it still doesn't show up. If it doesn't work even then, I have no idea.

Comment: The `--replace` option to unity is a no-op now (unity 7.5.0 in Ubuntu 19.04).  Is there another way of re-reading `.local/share/applications` ? I've lots of stuff in there from a prior installation that is never getting read (have tried login/logout)

Comment: Okay I've gotten to the bottom of it.  The `unity --replace` step is not needed as of 7.5.0; the dash gets updated in real-time.
My problem was that the target executable of the `Exec=` line was not installed on my computer (after a reinstall).  Somehow Unity detects this and hides those `.desktop` files that would not execute.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you install you the icon will be automatically added. But if it is not, then do the following:

1. Open the Unity dashboard.
2. Type main menu in the search bar. (In Germany you need to type "Hauptmenu")
3. Open it and select the best category your app fits (if you want create one).
4. Select insert item.
5. Type name, command (a terminal command or path to the executable) and comment.
6. Add the item.
7. Launch the item from the Unity dash board.