# How do I make an application appear in the dash?

Tags: 11.10, unity, applications-lens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add an application to the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash)

I have an app that I downloaded to `~/Documents/app-name`. How do I make it appear in the dash?

Symlink it somewhere? If yes, where?

( If I symlink the file in `/usr/bin` it is found with the ALT-F2 ("Run") search-box. But not the default one. )

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash