# Where place executables and how show them in the menu?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install a software (Modelio 3). I have a folder with an executable and I can launch the app with that exe .

But what I want to know is if I there is a folder like "Application" on Mac where I should paste the Modelio folder... and so the program will appear in the Application Menu.

Comment: What is your end objective? To have the program appear in the menu? To have it in your PATH so you can run it from the command line? Both?

Comment: I'm discovering Ubuntu (To be precise Voyager : [link](http://voyagerlive.org/)) and I want to know how to make a "clean" install.
I meant that the softwares I downloaded works great when I execute them from the Download repertory, but I guess there is a better repertory to place these softwares.

I read that the best directory for software I have (Modelio and  Sublime Text 2) was **/opt**. And thanks to the answer of @byaruhaf I managed to add the shortcuts in the menu!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. In any case, there is no "best" directory, executables are usually placed in `/usr/bin` but not the files they need. There is no need to do anything except, for convenience, you can [add the location of this program to your `$PATH`](http://askubuntu.com/q/60218/85695).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `gnome-desktop-item-edit`

For this you need `gnome-tweak-tool` or `gnome-shell` installed

Use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

This will open the dialog Create Launcher

[image: Create Launcher]

You can put this `.desktop` file in `/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/` to make it appear in the dash

### Using `alacarte`

For this method, you need `alacarte` installed.Do it by

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

And use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `alacarte`

You will get this dialog:

[image]

Select the category you want and click "New Item"

You will get this dialog

[image: Create launcher-alacarte]

Click OK . It will appear in the dash

---

*Sources:*

[Bruno Pereira's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78960/17722)

[Binarylife's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78968/17722)

[Kikixx's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/67781/17722)

Answer (score 0):

RAW text-files `.desktop` are used to start an application under Ubuntu.

Those `.desktop` files are stored in `/usr/share/applications/` and `~/.local/share/applications`.

---

Typical `.desktop` file construction :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=FALSE OR TRUE (MOST OF THE TIME 'FALSE')
Icon=PATH/TO/THE/ICON
Type=Application
Categories=CATEGORIES
Exec=COMMANDLINE TO START THE APPLICATION
MimeType=MIMETYPES WHICH WILL USE THIS PROGRAM WHEN CLICKED
Name=APPLICATION'S NAME
Comment=COMMENT TO DETAIL WHAT THE APPLICATION DOES
Keywords=SOME KEYWORDS SEPARATED BY ';' TO HELP THE DASH
```