# I created a desktop file in /usr/share/applications, but it doesn't show up in Dash

Tags: unity-dash, .desktop

I've created a .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;Oracle;Utility;Development;
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/sqldeveloper/icon.png
Name=Oracle SQL Developer
Comment=what to say
Version=s.0.m.t.h.i.n.g
GenericName=ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER
```

It is present in `/usr/share/applications` .It is even showing the icon if viewed in Nautilus, but when I press alt (the dash or  windows key) and search for it, it is not visible.

Also I tried:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the .desktop file? (and I think you mean the Windows -key?)

Comment: yeah, right, the windows key.

Comment: Have you (at least) tried relog? The "Version" string is very uncommon - might be an issue. AFAIK the bash commands should be placed between quotation marks.

Comment: There is a number of issues with your command, using it like that in a .desktop file. Change it and it is ok. I tried your file with another (working) command, then it works fine. I'll anwer it when it is reopened.

Comment: changed version string .still no result.

Comment: It's not the version string that causes the error.

Comment: 1) version should be 2 numbers `1.0` for ex 2) your Exec is wierd, how about `bash /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper $*` ? (not sure that you can use a wildcard like * in your exec line though) 3) GenericName is the same as Name ? There's no point in that... remove GenericName entry if you're gonna use the same string 4) Is the icon valid ? If the icon doesn't exist, it will most likely never be displayed in Dash 5) Oracle isn't a recognized Category, you should read [freedesktop's documentation](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) for more information

Comment: @MrVaykadji Most of what you say is not causing the file to be refused. did you try it? I guess not.

Comment: @JacobVlijm tried it right now. The error is definitively coming from the `Exec` line. Note that my previous comment is still true regarding freedesktop recommendation :p

Comment: Check [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156892/41104) so you can know what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @MrVaykadji Absolutely, all you say is true, but the Exec line is critical

Comment: This may be useful:http://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What is the critical issue in your .desktop file

I tried your .desktop file replacing the `Exec=` command with another (simple and working) one and the file appears to be functional, and is not refused by Dash.

It is a common misunderstanding that you can use the `Exec=` line of a .desktop file as if it were a terminal window. That is not the case; expanding like `~/` or `$HOME` doesn't work for example. It is good (meaning: easy) practice to place more complicated commands in a separate script file, to be executed from the launcher file (your `.desktop` file)

#### Running complicated commands from a .desktop file

If you specifically want to keep your command *inside* your `.desktop` file, you should make it as follows:

```
Exec=sh -c "your_complicated_command_here && the_rest_of_it"
(command inside quotes)
```

#### Running a script from the .desktop file to do the job

Assuming that your command

```
cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*
```

works from a terminal window, I would however simply create a small script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*
```

Save it as `scriptname.sh`, and change the `Exec=` line of your .desktop file into:

```
Exec=sh /path/to/scriptname.sh
```

Then your `.desktop` file will show up in Dash

#### Note

That there are more issues with your .desktop file, as mentioned by @Braiam and @MrVaykadji. A few examples:

- You should not use just use made up values in the `Categories=` line, as you can read [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html)
- The version field is not required, but if you use it, use 1.0

More can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156892/how-to-validate-verify-desktop-files). Good tools you can find [here](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/) (also thanks to @Braiam and @MrVaykadji).

The critical one that makes your .desktop file not appear in Dash however is the `Exec=` line.

Comment: this was a genuinely useful answer. There are a lot of answers on this topic that don't help! The issues I had were that my categories were not ones from the list, and that I referred to `/home/user` as `~`. Apparently it doesn't like that. You have to specify the whole /path/.