# "Add to Favorites" not available for manually created desktop item

Tags: .desktop

I installed one application in `/opt` (simply untarring) and had to create my own `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Icon=/opt/IntelliJ/bin/idea.svg
Exec=/opt/IntelliJ/bin/idea.sh
```

However, the application icon in the side bar does not offer **Add to Favorites** when right-clicked.

[image]

How can I enable that option?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but some people may benefit from this documentation on the format of desktop files:
https://developer-old.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#introduction

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this problem and I will share my notes in case it helps someone.

- If the `.desktop` file is for all users to use then it should be placed under `/usr/local/share/applications`.
- If the `.desktop` file is only for the current user then it should be placed under `~/.local/share/applications`.
- The `.desktop` file placed as above does not need execute permissions. It can be 0644.
- If the `.desktop` file has a key `Hidden` then it should be `Hidden=false`.
- If the `.desktop` file has a key `NoDisplay` then it should be `NoDisplay=false`.
- The `Exec` key should have a valid command. Bash commands may not work as detailed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/527154/997759).

With these settings in place the desktop entry should be searchable using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, and from there using the <kbd>Right Click</kbd> -> <kbd>Add to Favorites</kbd> option, it can be setup as a favorite on the dash.

**Note**: In the above bullet points, "Has a key" means if the key is present in the config file. Alternatively, it can be absent, in which case the default value for that key takes effect.

Comment: What does "has a key" mean in this context?  As in, `If the .desktop file has a key Hidden then ...`

Comment: @Stewart - Since .desktop files are configuration files they have key value pairs like `SomeKey=SomeValue`. That's what is referred to as key. Has a key means if the key is present in the config file. Alternatively, it can be absent, in which case the default value for that key takes effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.desktop` file should reside in `~/.local/share/applications`  or in an `applications` folders under one of the directories in the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environmental variable.

Thus, for your custom application, install the file under `~/.local/share/applications` if you are the only one needing to see the application in your user menu, or in `/usr/local/share/applications` to make it available for all users.

Once properly installed, you will also be able to add the launcher to your favorites.

Comment: I don't even have `applications` under my `/usr/local/share`

Comment: Nobody said you would. If you don't, make it. Indeed it is not there by default.

Comment: moving it to `/usr/local/share/applications` and logging back in to reload the KDE -- did not work.

Comment: This advice does not work on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @vanadium I literally used a working desktop file which I could set as a favorite, did nothing more than change the executable to a different (and very executable) program in the same folder, and copied it to /usr/local/share/ which is in my XDG_DATA_DIRS path. And after running that executable, there is no option to set it as a favorite. I ended up renaming the new program to the same name as the old program so that I could use the working desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add your launcher using the command line.

`dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps` to output a string representing the current favorites, e.g.  ['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop']

Copy the string and add your new launcher to the list. Run this to update your favorites:

`dconf write /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'YourManualApp.desktop']"`