# Opera - open with smooth scrolling

Tags: launcher, opera

I can launch opera manually from the CLI with smooth scrolling enabled like so:

```
/usr/bin/opera --enable-smooth-scrolling
```

However, if I launch opera through synapse or the unity launcher, opera will launch without smooth scrolling, which is much worse. How can I get Ubuntu to open opera with this command by default instead of just executing `/usr/bin/opera`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the "No new software method" answer from [How do I add an application to the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash) I was able to create an application called "Opera-new" just by creating a file at: `$HOME/.local/share/applications/opera.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Opera-new
Comment=
Exec=opera --new-window --enable-smooth-scrolling %U
Icon=opera
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

I was surprised that even the icon showed up correctly.
[image]

Unfortunately, changing `Opera-new` to just `Opera` in the config didn't have the desired result, so I had to come up with an alternative name for launching the application.