# Opera doesn't open links in other applications

Tags: opera

#### Problem

Whenever I click a link in an email from Thunderbird (or any non-browser application), Opera (which is my default browser) will open a new window to speed dial but not navigate to the address. **Is there a way to fix this?**

#### Workaround

I have to right click links and manually grab their addresses before pasting into the URI bar.

#### Extra Info

- Firefox and Chrome act as one would expect, so it is not an issue with Thunderbird.
- Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop 64 bit
- Opera version 32.0.1948.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

To link the Opera browser correctly to Thunderbird one must change the following in Thunderbird's `Edit/Preferences` under the tab `attachments`

- http : link to `/usr/bin/opera`
- https : link to `/usr/bin/opera`

These are actually symbolic links to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera` (this is at least so for Ubuntu 15.10)

**Option 2**
Another option is to edit the opera.desktop file (`~/.local/share/applications/opera.desktop`) where instead of `Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera` one must specify `Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera %U`, the latter taking the argument (http or https link) and opening a page there.

Comment: For future reference and to be inclusive, if you're using the beta version change to `opera-beta` and, obviously, the `opera-developer` version where applicable. This is also the case in at least 15.04 as well - and is the same in Lubuntu and Kubuntu. This is just to give some extra information to the answer for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that I had already created an opera.desktop file at that location because of [this earlier issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671509/opera-open-with-smooth-scrolling) in which adding the `%U` worked. However I don't think there is a file there by default. I couldn't find anything in Thunderbird for option 1, but as I said, option 2 did the trick.

Comment: Just added `%U` to the answer in the [askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671509/opera-open-with-smooth-scrolling) I referred to earlier.