# Adding a launcher item for a terminal program that has no UI

Tags: unity, launcher

Please see the edit at the bottom!

I have followed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) for adding an item to the launcher. Here are the contents of my new .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=OpenRefine
Comment=2.6-rc.2
Path=/home/foo/openrefine-2.6-rc.2
Exec=/home/foo/openrefine-2.6-rc.2/refine
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

(no icon supplied by the application so none included, hopefully a default one will be used). `desktop-file-validate` passes without errors. So does `desktop-file-install`. Yet the new program does not show in dash :(

I have started out saving the .desktop file to .local/share/applications, so it is also confusing whether it should remain there after the `desktop-file-install` or rather it should have been created in some temporary place to begin with, rather than there.

Thanks for clarifying how this should be done.

## Edit:

Notably, this program, OpenRefine, when started in a terminal, does not open a UI window. It only starts a web server and launches the default browser against it.

Comment: Your Exec= is wrong, /home must start with slash

Comment: It is correct in the real file, I just introduced that error while replacing the real local file path for pasting the question

Comment: In the real file, do you by any chance use `~`?

Comment: Did, you try to do a reboot after you created that file? Sometimes after a reboot the icon which was missing in the dash before is then there.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I do deserve the question now :-) but no: the path is valid. I would like to also assume the verification command would otherwise issue an error. But double-checked the path now just to be on the safe side ― it is fine.

Comment: I've added a _crucial_ edit and re-titled the question now. We can all remove our comments here I guess now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Main Menu" app (install with `sudo apt install alacarte`).
Run it from Dash or from Terminal (`alacarte`).
Then you can add launcher item:

1. Choose category from list on left
2. Click "New item" button
3. Insert needed information into fields
4. Click "OK" and close.

Now you should have your icon on launcher.

Comment: I upvoted this, but this silently does nothing, same as the command line approach.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
sh -c "cd /home/foo/openrefine-2.6-rc.2 && ./refine"
```

in the place of

```
/home/foo/openrefine-2.6-rc.2/refine
```

in the code above.

You can also use $HOME instead of `/home/foo`, where foo is your username.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This is very similar @Ven3k but more complete, with a lot of screenshots. Also is very similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/112812/349837) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/986794/349837) answers but specifically for [Openrefine](http://openrefine.org).

---

You can create a shortcut to any program and eventually add it to dock/taskbar/launchbar by:

1. Go to *Main menu* program (`alacarte` package): From Show Applications or just hit <kbd>Super</kbd> (win) key.

   [image: screenshot]
2. "New item", complete the filename, browse for the exacutable program:

   [image: screenshot]
3. **Optional:** Add a cute icon: Clic on the icon and search for it. For openrefine you can download one or you will find one on `myOpenRefineFolder/webapp/modules/core/images/logo-gem-126.png`

   [image: screenshot]

   [image: screenshot]

   [image: screenshot]
4. **Optional** Add it to dock/launchbar/taskbar:

   [image: screenshot]

   [image: screenshot]

If you clic and nothing happen try to run the same command path directly on a terminal. If another Openrefine instance (or other program) is using the same port you'll get a

```
Error: Something is already running on http://127.0.0.1:3333/ but doesn't seem to be OpenRefine. Maybe a proxy issue?
```

Find the culprit with `ss -tlpn | grep 3333`. If you get a PID you can then `kill PID` it.