# How do I pin my favorite folders in Ubuntu dock like in Windows?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

[image]

I want like above screenshot for quick access to my file/folder.

Comment: One way could be creating a custom `.desktop` file for nautilus.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to pin folder `Downloads` (and then others, I guess)... but you are posting an image where you already have it.
What do you want, different from what you have?
It would help-others-help-you posting how you got to the point you are, and what is missing.
Also, why the answers (at least the most upvoted) do not satisfy your requirement. There is no feedback from you in any of the answers, so it is hard to tell how to improve on them.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio i want exactly as shown in the picture.. none of the answer below fulfills it.. above is just some editing i did in pinta.

Comment: @nazar2sfive are you using default ubuntu dock or any other?

Answer (score 28):

Follow the steps below.

1. Create a `.desktop` file (say `custom-filemanager.desktop`) in `~/.local/share/applications`. You can do this by running the following command in Terminal

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/custom-filemanager.desktop
   ```
2. Open the `.desktop` file using a text-editor, for example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/custom-filemanager.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following lines to the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=File Manager
   Comment=Access and organize files
   Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
   Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
   Icon=org.gnome.Nautilus
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
   Actions=new-window;open-downloads;

   [Desktop Action new-window]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=nautilus --new-window
   [Desktop Action open-downloads]
   Name=Open my Downloads folder
   Exec=nautilus /home/YOUR-USER-NAME/Downloads
   ```

   Replace `YOUR-USER-NAME` by your user-name in the last line.
4. Save the file.
5. Click on "*Activities*" and search for "File Manager". It should appear.
6. Right click on the "File Manager" and select "Add to Favourites". It should be added to the dock.

Now if you right click on the newly added File Manager icon in the dock, you should see a "Open my Downloads folder" option which should work as expected.

[image]

Similarly you can add shortcuts to other locations by adding new `Desktop Action`s and adding the name of the action to the `Actions=` line. For more info see [this](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#extra-actions).

Comment: Hi there, Using Ubuntu 18.04 here. Your advice almost worked as expected. But by following your instructions I got two issues:

1. There are, now, two nautilus icons on applications overview;

2. When the new nautilus icon is pinned in the dock and I choose, for example, "open my download folders", the default nautilus icon appear in the dock with the Download folder (when the Download folder is supposed to open in the new created icon itself). As a result I end up with two nautilus icons in the dock as well.

Do you know how to fix these?

Comment: @alex The first one is kinda intended, to distinguish from the system one. You can hide the system one by adding a `NoDisplay=true` line to the associated `.desktop` launcher. For the second part you need to add a correct `StartupWMClass` entry to the `.desktop` file: https://askubuntu.com/q/975178/480481 If it still doesn't work, then there might be a bug with Ubuntu dock, you may have to report at launchpad.net.

Comment: After some attemps I figured out how to make it work properly. Thank you for the tips, I'll post a new answer in this topic explaning how to make it work in Ubuntu 18.04 for users who may need it.

Comment: @AlexGóesFuhrmann it would be good to put a link to your answer here so we can directly go there

Answer (score 7):

As we can pin only Application to Gnome Dock, the best available option here is creating an application launcher that will open the favorite directory directly with a single mouse click.

1. So in order to do that navigate to activities and search for "Main menu".

   [image: screenshot]

   Now you will get a window titled  **Main menu**.
2. Click on  <kbd>New item</kbd>. and You will get a small window and fill the fields like described below.

   In the given example I am pinning my `Videos` directory to Dock.

   [image: screenshot]

   And now it will be shown at the bottom of the main menu window like this

   [image: screenshot].
3. Click on <kbd>close</kbd> button and again go to activities and search for the the "Name" provided. In my case its "My Videos". Single click on that and just drag and drop it to the `Gnome dock`.

   Now You will get the shortcut on your Dock.

   [image: screenshot]

If you click on that you will get your favorite directory which you set opened by nautilus.

#### Tweaks

You can do more tweaks like changing the icon of the application launcher you want while creating the shortcut of even after creating the shortcut and pinning it.

After tweaking my shortcut (My Videos) is like this.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

**Here is how to make it in Ubuntu 18.04:**

1. Open Files, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and paste `/usr/share/applications`.
2. Look for the "Files" icon and copy it (right click > Copy)

   > Note: in my system, I don't know why, there are tree  "Files" icon. For this procedure I selected the first one, which has 2,7kB. To make sure it'll work in your computer I recommend you to do the same.
3. Now open your personal folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files.
4. Once you've done it, navigate to `.local/share/applications` and paste the file you copied in the step 2 into this folder.
5. You'll see a new icon called `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`. Right click on it and select "Open with other application". Select the Text Editor to open it and replace the content of the file with the following:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Files
   Comment=Access and organize files
   Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
   Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
   Icon=org.gnome.Nautilus
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
   StartupWMClass=nautilus;Nautilus
   Actions=new-window;open-documents;open-downloads;open-pictures;open-music;open-videos;

   [Desktop Action new-window]
   Name=New window
   Exec=nautilus --new-window

   [Desktop Action open-documents]
   Name=Documents
   Exec=nautilus /home/YOUR-USER-NAME/Documents

   [Desktop Action open-downloads]
   Name=Downloads
   Exec=nautilus /home/YOUR-USER-NAME/Downloads

   [Desktop Action open-pictures]
   Name=Pictures
   Exec=nautilus /home/YOUR-USER-NAME/Pictures

   [Desktop Action open-music]
   Name=Music
   Exec=nautilus /home/YOUR-USER-NAME/Music

   [Desktop Action open-videos]
   Name=Videos
   Exec=nautilus /home/YOUR-USER-NAME/Videos
   ```

   Replace `YOUR-USER-NAME` by your username.
6. Save the document and close it. You're done!

> Note: If your system is in another language that not English replace the words of the filds `Name=` and `Exec=` of the desired `[Desktop Action]` for the equivalent in your language. See an example in Portuguese above:
>
> ```
> [Desktop Action open-pictures]
> Name=Pictures
> Exec=nautilus /home/YOUR-USER-NAME/Pictures
> ```
>
> Is going to be:
>
> ```
> [Desktop Action open-pictures]
> Name=Imagens
> Exec=nautilus /home/YOUR-USER-NAME/Imagens
> ```
>
> Finally, replace the word of the field `Name=Files` of `[Desktop Entry]` according to what `Files` means in your language. In Portuguese,
>   for example, Files is translated Arquivos, so I had to change
>   `Name=Files` to `Name=Arquivos`. If you don't do this, you'll end up with two Files icons with different names in your computer.

---

### Final result

[image]

Comment: The 3 files are *nautilus.desktop*, *nautilus-folder-handle.desktop*, and *org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop*. I also don't know what's the difference between the 3, but on my system the file sizes were different, and I only knew I copied the wrong file because what I pasted wasn't *org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop*.

Comment: An easier way to get this result is to `sudo apt-get install pcmanfm` and then `pcmanfm` to launch the pcmanfm file manager, navigate to the folder, right-click and add to favourites.

Answer (score 2):

It's not prefect for what you seek, but you might be interested in the [Gno-Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/608/gnomenu/) extension.

The extension adds a quite configurable menu. The following shows it's default:

[image]

The recent documents I have accessed are shown on the right. The shortcuts on the left are set to the Places of Nautilus. The highlighted folder shortcut is to a folder I have "pinned" in Nautilus.

The Recents overview does not seem to support viewed folders. I don't know how the "Link to Intro etc." link got in there. Creating a new link to a folder and opening it did not put the folder there, and roaming in Nautilus does not affect Recents (until you open a file).

The right-hand side can also be configured to show your Favorites from the overview, where you could then add `.desktop` entries for Nautilus to open specific folders. (See [pomsky's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/985273/13884), but use `Exec=nautilus /home/user/folder/ --new-window %U` and include only the `[Desktop Entry]` part.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think getting "exactly" what you composed with `pinta` is feasible, if not dealing directly with code in GTK or other packages. In that case, this OP is more suitable for stackoverflow.

I guess you will increase your chances of getting something useful if you specify which aspects of the difference between your image and [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3QK3.png) by pomsky you require as mandatory.

For instance, if you *need* the titles "Pinned" and "Frequent", plus the separators, that is likely built into GTK or else.
If you mostly want to get access to some "Pinned" folders, without the title, that is already available.
If you are ok with adding the "Frequent" folders, without the title, that is perhaps doable with a dynamic script that reads the information stored as per *Settings* -> *Privacy* -> *File History & Trash*, which should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome 42.4) you can easily pin your application from Dash search:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be much simpler.
When you open an application or a folder,
it shows in your dock by default.
When you close it, it goes away.
So when it IS open and showing in your dock,
Right-Click the icon and "Add to Favourites",
then it will remain and live happily in your dock.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Can you really pin a *specific* **folder** (*not* an application) as the question asks for by this "Add to Favourites" method? I don't think you can.

Comment: No hence the down vote. I assumed too much. However... An easier way to get this result is to `sudo apt-get install pcmanfm` and then `pcmanfm` to launch the pcmanfm file manager, navigate to the folder, right-click and add to favourites.

Comment: You mean "add to *bookmarks*"? That's not the same as what's being asked here though. And bookmarking is a feature of almost all (if not all) file managers.