# Duplicate application icons in Ubuntu dock upon launch

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME shell and Numix-Circle icon theme.

When I hover over the Numix icon for Nightly Web Browser, which is pinned to the dock I get the title "Nightly Web Browser".

[image]

But when I launch the program, another icon pops up at the bottom, with the name "Nightly".

[image]

Answer (score 81):

You need to add a proper `StartupWMClass` line to the `.desktop` launcher corresponding to the application (refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-represent-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file)). Follow these steps:

1. Open Files and go to your `/usr/share/applications` folder. Look for the "Nightly" file (i.e. the launcher for the application you want to fix) and copy it.
2. Paste the file in `~/.local/share/applications`. It should look like a file with the name `<filename>.desktop`.
3. Right click on this `.desktop` file and open with Text Editor.
4. Launch "Nightly" (i.e. the application you want to fix) from "*Activities*".
5. Run `xprop WM_CLASS` in Terminal.
6. Place the cursor over the opened "Nightly" window. The cursor should turn into a crosshair already. Click. You should get a `WM_CLASS` string for "Nightly" in Terminal.
7. In the `.desktop` file opened in Text Editor add the following line

   ```
   StartupWMClass=OBTAINED-VALUE
   ```

   In place of `OBTAINED-VALUE` put a value you got from step 6 without any quotes.
8. Save the `.desktop` file.

Comment: I am trying to do the same with PyCharm. Got `"sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "jetbrains-pycharm-ce"` as the output for step 6. I used `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce` and it works.

Comment: 9. Rename .desktop file to OBTAINED-VALUE.desktop (e.g. jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop instead phpstorm.desktop), works in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would be really nice to have an explanation of what happens. I don't want to blindly follow some instructions. What is going on and what does the fix do? Would be great if someone could help out.

Comment: @marts Please go through this for an explanations: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-represent-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file

Comment: @AlekseyDeryagin In step 6, I got `WM_CLASS:  not found`. As the misbehaving application was kile and the name of the file `org.kde.kile.desktop`, I just added the line `StartupWMClass=kile` and it works. My wild guess is that the last full-stop separated part of the filename (right before `.desktop`) should match the StartupWMClass value.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Worked with Qt5 Creator on Ubuntu 18.04 (`StartupWMClass=QtCreator`).

Comment: @AlekseyDeryagin My only worry there is if the .desktop file was installed by a package manager, I wonder if it could cause conflicts/confusion in future updates/uninstalls if I forget I renamed it; otoh putting a copy in .local keeps me from touching package files. Do you think that could be an issue?

Comment: As a side note, if you run gnome-shell under Wayland, xprop won't work. You can use Alt+F2 and run 'lg' (look glass). Under the Window tab, you get the WMClass. Notice it works also under X.

Comment: When an Audio CD is in the external USB DVD drive, every time machine resumes from suspend another icon appears in the launcher. The solution is in this answer with the line `StartupWMClass="desktop_window", "Nautilus"` inserted (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

Comment: This solution doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 with VS Code.

Comment: it works very well on mine. @Chantz you should mark this answer as accepted if this work for you.

Comment: I've tried all - to no avail. But if I name the desktop file exactly like the WmClass name it seems to work in Gnome. - Strange DE that

Comment: Some programs (which are listed in my left navigation) are not even listed in the folder /usr/share/applications, so this 'guide' here cannot be followed for them. I suppose that in this case I am supposed to create that file on my own? Is there an easy to follow 'manual' for each required line -- similar to this one? :)

Comment: @prof It depends on how you have installed those applications. If you installed the snap version of the application, then this would help: https://askubuntu.com/q/1199337/480481. Check this one out if you want to create the `.desktop` launchers by hand anyway: https://askubuntu.com/q/13758/480481 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1191962/480481

Comment: Thanks, man! I've fixed my sublime installed from `*.tar.bz` on Ubuntu 20.04. 
I've just added `StartupWMClass=sublime_text` to `sublime.desktop`)

Answer (score 10):

#### Ubuntu 20.04 on Wayland

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type "lg" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Looking Glass)
3. Click on the "Windows" tab.
4. You should see the titles of all your windows. Below each one you will find a `wmclass` property. Write down or copy the value you see.
5. Open up the `.desktop` config file corresponding to your application. It should be in the `~/.local/share/applications/` folder.
6. On a new line add `StartupWMClass=VALUE_FROM_ABOVE`

In my case for Firefox it was "Firefox Developer Edition" and I had to add the line below to my `.desktop` file:

```
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
```

Comment: `wmclass` does not work for Ubuntu 21.10, instead `StartupWMClass` worked for me.

Comment: Good catch @shvahabi, would you like to make that an edit on the answer? Just so stackoverflow gives you credit for the edit.

Comment: No, since there are already answers below with same detailed explanation.

Comment: I think "wmclass" was more likely an error I made when writing this answer. I updated the answer to avoid further confusion.

Comment: So after doing all this, would it reflect immediately? Nothing happens on me on Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: @NeonWarge I have yet to find a good way to test the validity of an application file. Unfortunately the only way seems to be search for the application, and if it doesn't show up in search, then there's something wrong with the formatting.

Comment: I like this solution because is points to the existence of "looking glass" feature.

Answer (score 4):

related to :

> Kile icon buggy in left (launcher) bar (ubuntu 18.04)

On ubuntu 18.04

- open the file : `org.kde.kile.desktop`
- at :  `/usr/share/applications`
- add this line at the end of file : `StartupWMClass=kile`
- press ALT+F2, r

It works for me

Comment: This keeps working for Ubuntu 20.04. I hope it will be solved in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

In my case with Adobe Reader 9 on Ubuntu 20.04, the function **StartupWMClass=Acroread** works instead of **wmclass=Acroread**

Comment: Your answer as is right now needs some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I followed @Chris Hayes, method of finding the WMClass and update the file, see below for an example. I referred other *.desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` and found that Ubuntu 20.04 is using "StartupWMClass" as the variable and NOT "WMClass". I could not find the Icon for this application so I had to download from the internet a jpeg file icon from Google Image search, save it in the path and assign to the variable "Icon".
Please note, I believe this field "StartupWMClass" is case sensitive

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PDFStudioViewer2020
Comment=View pdf documents
Keywords=pdf;ppdf;
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Office;Viewer;X-Red-Hat-Base;
MimeType=application/pdf;application/ppdf;
Icon=/opt/pdfstudioviewer2020/pdfstudio_internet_icon.jpeg
Exec=/opt/pdfstudioviewer2020/pdfstudioviewer2020 %F
StartupWMClass=PDF Studio Viewer
```