# Okular instances does not group under single icon in desktop dock on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu-dock, dock, okular

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, multiple instances of `okular` will no longer group under a single icon in the desktop dock.

I am running 17.10 under X.org, and if it matters: I am viewing PDF files with `okular`. All other applications I have tested work correctly. For example, multiple instances of `gnome-terminal` and `emacs` will group under a single item in the desktop dock. There was no problem with grouping for `okular` in 17.04.

Why is it important to have them grouped? It enables one to use a keyboard shortcut to switch between applications of the same type (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>). It also makes it easier to switch between different applications (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) since there are fewer instances to cycle through.

How can I get `okular` instances to group correctly in 17.10?

Comment: I had the same issue with okular, you running the snap app version ?

Comment: @pomsky Great! I think it works. There are many desktop files for `okular` in `/usr/share/applications`. I chose the one called : `okularApplication_pdf.desktop` and added the line : `StartupWMClass=okular` to the end of that file.

Comment: One small trivia, the combination you mentioned as alt+| is written as "alt+key-above-tab" in documentations. The reason is there is no global standard for that key, in many keyboards it's the backtick (`) key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Copy the `okularApplication_pdf.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`. For that you may run

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/okularApplication_pdf.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. Open the copied file with a text editor. For example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/okularApplication_pdf.desktop
   ```
3. Add (or modify) the following line to the file

   ```
   StartupWMClass=okular
   ```
4. Save the file.

Adapted from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975230/480481).

**Edit:**

If you have installed `okular` as a `snap`, you will find the desktop file at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/okular_org.kde.okular.desktop`

In this case the following could become your step 1:

```
cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/okular_org.kde.okular.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Then follow steps 2 to 4 as mentioned in the previous method.

Comment: On Debian 9, the desktop file is at `/usr/share/applications/kde4/okular.desktop`

Comment: If you have installed `okular` as a `snap`, you will find the desktop file at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/okular_org.kde.okular.desktop`