# State of Okular in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, icons, kde, qt, okular

With Ubuntu 17.10, Okular (installed through the Ubuntu repositories, i. e. `apt install okular`) seems to work a lot worse than in previous versions. This is both on Wayland and on the X session. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Okular window]

For example: As you can see, only the item “Contents” in the left sidebar has an icon. The other ones (“Thumbnails”, “Reviews”, “Bookmarks”) should have icons as well (see e. g. [this screenshot](https://okular.kde.org/images/screenies/okular-backend-pdf-1.png)).

Moreover, when I open Okular from the Terminal, I get a bunch of output:

> ```
> inotify_add_watch("/home/user/.config/ibus/bus/9f77c45ee0ec4b6a89aaaa7669ff56c1-unix-0") failed: "No space left on device"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/16/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/22/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/24/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/32/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/48/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/64/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/128/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/16/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/22/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/24/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/32/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/48/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/64/"
> Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/128/"
> ```

The messages about the icon theme might be related to the missing icons. The first line apparently means that the limit of inotify watches has been reached – why is that happening?

Lastly, the UI theme looks nothing like other applications in Ubuntu (I guess this is a problem with Qt applications in general?) – look at the scroll bars, for example. I suppose this has to do with the move back to GNOME? It used to be much better in Ubuntu versions before 17.10.

Is there any way to fix/work around these issues?

---

As another data point, there is the question [“Okular instances do not group under single icon in desktop dock on Ubuntu 17.10”](https://askubuntu.com/q/995693), but that already has a solution in the link.

Comment: Okular, is neither gnome nor Qt. It is KDE and plasma. And I belive it requires the KDE oxygen theme.

Comment: @ravery Well, isn’t KDE built on Qt (just like GNOME is on GTK)? I’ve tried installing the packages `oxygen-icon-theme` and `oxygen5-icon-theme`, with no effect.

Comment: maybe it is Qt on plasma; but anyway, are you using Wayland (default) or Xorg. I don't think KDE plays well with Wayland yet.

Comment: You can try to play with `qtconfig-qt4`.

Comment: Could you update the question to include the method you used to install it?

Comment: @ravery I don’t see a difference no matter whether I use the Wayland or the X.org session

Comment: @gsxruk Done: Installed via `apt install okular`.

Answer (score 5):

Install qt5ct:

```
sudo apt install qt5ct
```

Run:

```
qt5ct --platformtheme qt5ct
```

and set the icon-theme to breeze. (You may do other modifications as you wish)

Set the appropriate evironment variable:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

and add this line:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
```

Reboot.

If this doesn't work continue with the following:
Then copy the okular .desktop file to your home folder:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/org.kde.okular.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Modify the copied .desktop file by changing the line:

```
Exec=okular %U
```

to

```
Exec=okular --platformtheme qt5ct %U
```

Open the `~/.local/share/applications` folder in Files and run Okular. It will ask you to trust the application the first time.

Done.

Comment: Linux Mint, works perfect now!

Comment: In more recent versions of Ubuntu, this is what fixes the icons (which are still broken by default, two years later!) for me.

Answer (score 3):

My current status:

1. **Missing icons:** I found a solution to this in a [comment on Launchpad bug #1698656 (“navigation panel icons missing on standard install of 17.04”)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/okular/+bug/1698656/comments/4):

   > As a workaround, what worked for me was:
   >
   > `$ sudo apt install systemsettings kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-gtk-style-preview oxygen-icon-theme`
   >
   > - systemsettings for the app systemsettings5;
   > - kde-config-gtk-style enables the Appearance module in systemsettings5;
   > - kde-config-gtk-style-preview allows previewing the themes without restarting the GTK applications;
   > - oxygen-icon-theme is an alternative theme to use in KDE applications.
   >
   > Then, run systemsettings5, click on Application Style, select Oxygen
   >   as a Fallback theme, click on Apply.

   I used “Breeze” instead of “Oxygen” as a fallback theme, though (because I like it more).
2. **Error messages on the terminal:** Still unsolved, although the issue of running out of inotify watches seems to have disappeared?
3. **Inconsistent UI theme (e. g. scroll bars):** Still unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

Using a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10, I also tried installing using `sudo apt install okular` and received the same issue as you have reported.

However, it does appear to work if it is installed as a snap.

**Remove the currently installed okular:**

```
sudo apt remove okular
```

**Install as a snap:**

```
sudo snap install okular
```

Trying to run okular from the terminal then gives the following:

```
You need to connect this snap to the kde-frameworks-5 snap.

You can do this with those commands: snap install kde-frameworks-5
snap connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug
kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-slot
```

**Connect okular to the kde frameworks snap:**

```
sudo snap install kde-frameworks-5
sudo snap connect okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-slot
```

**Running okular then gives the following:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the current version of the Okular snap has a host of other problems, like being unable to access files outside the user’s home directory or any printers. Also, there were still some icons missing in “Settings → Configure Okular”.

Comment: Yeah, promising and pretty, but snap's Okular just crashed when I tried to save an annotated PDF

Answer (score 0):

For me, installing the `frameworkintegration` package (mentioned in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=220907) post) fixed it.

```
sudo apt install frameworkintegration
```