# GNOME 3: how to 'ungroup' applications and window

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I already read branch
[Okular instances does not group under single icon in desktop dock on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995693/okular-instances-does-not-group-under-single-icon-in-desktop-dock-on-ubuntu-17-1)

and I want to do some 'reverse' process. I want somehow two versions of qtCreator (stable and beta) to be independed. For example I run 'qt creator beta' but I see that GNOME caption is given from stable. Moreover, when I try to 'Add To Favorites' I ended up with adding of stable launch instead of beta one. 
I played a bit with both desktop files with no luck yet.

Comment: How did you "play a bit" with the desktop files? Changing the StartupWMClass setting in each of the .desktop files to a different identifier may do the trick, but chances are also it will not work: it also depends on the executable, and whether it launches other processes

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1000818/480481

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work since qtcreator doesn't understand '--class' argument. It is not a native gtk window. Is it possible to the same trick without gtk magic?