# On Ubuntu 18 Terminator windows are not grouped under same icon in Dock in a Wayland session

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock, wayland, terminator

I recently bumped into a very itchy problem on Ubuntu 18.04.

That is for each started terminator windows a dedicated icon is created on Dock. Additionally, these icons are shown as "not identified" applications:

[image]

The of all of this is that I cannot use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between related applications.
The case is pretty similar to the one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995693/okular-instances-does-not-group-under-single-icon-in-desktop-dock-on-ubuntu-17-1).
I followed that post and updated

`/usr/shar/applications/terminator.desktop` with `StartupWMClass=terminator`

```
dpoliaru@linux:/usr/share/applications$ cat terminator.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminator
Comment=Multiple terminals in one window
TryExec=terminator
Exec=terminator
Icon=terminator
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;System;
StartupNotify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=terminator
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;
Keywords=terminal;shell;prompt;command;commandline;
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=terminator
TargetEnvironment=Unity
StartupWMClass=terminator
```

But still I cannot switch with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> between terminator windows.
Please let me know what I might have missed to check.

I chose the option to login with 'Ubuntu on Wayland' to fix my other problem of Ubuntu not detecting DELL displays attached to laptop.

Comment: Yes. Just by chance, yesterday I found option to login with 'Ubuntu on Wayland' when fixing my other problem: Ubuntu does not detect DELL displays attached to laptop.
And indeed swithcing back to default 'Ubuntu' fixes the issue with terminator windows. But my 2 displays go down)) But that is a different question. Thanks! You can post this as an answer, so that it is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct `StartupWMClass=` line (which you already added) in your `.desktop` launcher for the application usually fixes this problem , but this sometimes fails in a Wayland session (see: [bug1](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1585492), [bug2](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1585369)).

Until the bug is fixed, one possible (may not be preferable though) workaround would be to [switching to a good ol' Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/q/961304/480481).