# Every Files window shows up as a separate icon in the dock (Wayland only)

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, wayland, dock, ubuntu-dock

[image: screenshot]

Every time I open a new window of Files, its icon shows up as a separate one from the pinned one. This also happens for Blender (snap version). This never happened for Files in 17.04 (but happened to Blender), but since I upgraded to 17.10 it started happening, because then I switched to Wayland. It does not happen in the Xorg session on 17.10. How can I stop it from making separate icons for each window and group them in the main pinned icon?

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-icons-in-the-dock-of-gnome-shell-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: @pomsky It didn't work. Wouldn't receive `WM_CLASS`

Comment: [Switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) from Wayland first. There you should  be able to get the strings.

Comment: @pomsky the bug doesn't exist in Xorg anyway, and even after doing what that answer suggested in Xorg then going back to Wayland, the bug still exists. I think that answer is a solution only for Xorg.