# Eclipse app icon not showing in switcher (alt+tab)

Tags: 17.10, icons, eclipse, gnome-shell, application-switcher

I installed the latest Eclipse as per the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse), and the icon shows fine in the launcher, but shows as a blank icon with an exclamation mark when using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch between applications. Should I copy the `eclipse.xpm` file to another folder other than `usr/share/pixmaps/` so the switcher can see it, or what should I do?

Image: Switching between apps with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>:
[image: Image: Switching between apps with ALT+TAB]
 versus launcher icons:
[image: launcher icons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `.desktop` file associated with Eclipse. Add the following line to the file and save the file:

```
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

Comment: Also works on Debian Buster. Please consider linking to some documentation that explains why this works and how to find what should be added in the `.desktop` file for other cases.

Comment: @olivier Please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975230/480481).