# XFCE (Xubuntu) Alt-Tab switcher: missing app icons

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, application-switcher

I have missing icons for Slack and MailSpring (Electron based apps I believe) in Xubuntu 18.04 application switcher:

[image]

The application's icon appears correctly everywhere else (i.e. in panels, app launchers, etc.) - it is only the switcher that is not working.

I have tried solution from here with no luck: [App icon not showing in switcher (alt+tab)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011815/app-icon-not-showing-in-switcher-alttab)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Seems to be caused by this bug in xfwm4: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11777

Raised in 2015. Going to look into this a little and see if there is a workaround or if I can provide the fix. Someone suggesting:

> The root may be in xfwm4/src/icons.c getAppIcon function

So we could have a head start on this problem