# Slack Icon Missing in Desktop Application Window in Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, icons, slack

I'm using the Slack desktop client on Xubuntu 20.04 and noticed that the Slack icon does not appear in the top left corner of the application window:

[image]

I've tried this with the *.deb package, the Snap package, and the Flatpak package, and all have the same problem. I'd welcome any insights the community can provide. Thanks!

**EDIT:** The problem is specific to Slack. I'm getting the expected icons on most other desktop applications. Here are a few examples from Firefox, KeePassXC, and Mousepad:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have Slack installed too in Xubuntu and it never shows that icon in that corner of the app.  If you want it to be there I would suggest you ask Slack themselves to modify their code to put the icon in that corner for you.  None of the applications I can see have their icons in their upper left corners.

Comment: Most other applications on Xubuntu show the icon without a problem. I wonder why Slack is an issue.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot then of an app showing that icon in the upper left corner?  Absolutely none of mine have an icon there.  They are either a down arrow for a menu or nothing.

Comment: I just edited the original post.

Comment: Ah, OK.  It is a Windows Manager theme that controls whether you see the icon in the upper left corner or not.  It could be that the Windows Manager theme that your system is set to may not have the icon for Slack.  Or it might be an issue of Slack itself missing the icon.  Are you using the snap version of Slack or the .deb version?

Comment: I believe I was using the Snap version in the above screenshot. I'm now using the Flatpak version and have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further research revealed that this is a known issue with Slack in XFCE, since Slack does not properly expose its icon to the windows manager. The workaround is to set the icon manually using `xseticon`. The links below detail the problem and the fix. In my case, it involved writing a script that ran after Slack opened and set the icon properly.  A highly simplified version looks like this one from one of the mentioned links:

```
function change-panel-icon {

    sleep $WAIT
    activeWinLine=$(xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)")
    activeWinId="${activeWinLine:40}"

    xseticon -id "$activeWinId" "$ICON"
}

$APP & change-panel-icon
```

The Spotify app has a similar issue, and it sounds like some other Electron apps do as well. Hopefully this will be fixed in a future XFWM release.

**XFCE (Xubuntu) Alt-Tab switcher: missing app icons - Ask Ubuntu**
[XFCE (Xubuntu) Alt-Tab switcher: missing app icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076366/xfce-xubuntu-alt-tab-switcher-missing-app-icons)

**Missing icon and app/window not present in application switcher · Issue #37 · flathub/com.slack.Slack · GitHub**
https://github.com/flathub/com.slack.Slack/issues/37

**[SOLVED] Applications to the right and Slack icon problem / Desktop / Xfce Forums**
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=13149

**Customize icon app on panel running apps and workspace ? / Desktop / Xfce Forums**
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=45963#p45963

**15510 – Icons for slack "desktop" application not visible in the window decoration and the task switcher**
https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15510

**Slack snap - window has no icon - snap - snapcraft.io**
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/slack-snap-window-has-no-icon/3589/40