# Duplicate icon in GNOME dock when instance is opened

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, wayland, ubuntu-dock

**NB:** My question is essentially identical to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/975178/315775), but it was recommended I open a new question as the given solution doesn't work.

Basically, I have Firefox Develop Edition installed. I managed to add the icon to the dock, and changed the icon to be correct. As such, I am 100% certain this is the correct `.desktop` file to be editing.

This is my `firefox-developer.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Icon=/home/jhpratt/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Exec=/home/jhpratt/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/firefox %u
Comment=Firefox Aurora with Developer tools
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
```

The final line of this is what the recommended solution in the post above is. Running `xprop WM_CLASS` and clicking on the Firefox window returns `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox Developer Edition"`. I have tried setting `StartupWMClass` to `Navigator`, `Firefox Developer Edition`, and `Navigator, Firefox Developer Edition`, none of which have worked. I restarted my session in between.

**Update:** It does not work in a Wayland session, but works as expected in Xorg.

Comment: Are you in a Wayland session? What happens if you [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)?

Comment: It does not work in a Wayland session, but works as expected in Xorg. I was under the impression that Xorg is the older, less favored, of the two, however.

Comment: Wayland is certainly more secure than Xorg, but I'm not sure about the "*less favored*" part though. Many feel Wayland is not ready yet to completely replace X. In fact Ubuntu developers have decided to ship the next LTS release (18.04) with X as default instead of Wayland.

Comment: Software requirements state that `X.Org 1.0 or higher (1.7 or higher is recommended)` is required.  See https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/58.0.2/system-requirements/

Comment: @Terrance That doesn't make much sense, cause I was still running FF under Wayland. It's _just_ the icon.

Comment: @jhpratt you were probably running FF in XWayland in Wayland, not in Wayland directly.