# .desktop shortcut behaves differently when added to dock

Tags: gnome, 18.04, 17.10, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I made a custom `.desktop` file to start my favourite terminal, Tilix, with my preferred session. The file is identical to the default, except for the `Exec` and `DBusActivatable` lines.

`~/.local/share/applications/com.gexperts.Tilix.desktop` (i18n lines omitted):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Tilix
Comment=A tiling terminal for Gnome
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;
Exec=tilix -s /home/phydeaux/.tilix/Default.json
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;X-GNOME-Utilities;
Icon=com.gexperts.Tilix
DBusActivatable=false
Actions=new-window;new-session;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=tilix --action=app-new-window

[Desktop Action new-session]
Name=New Session
Exec=tilix --action=app-new-session
```

I then added this shortcut to the dock by searching for it and using "Add to Favourites".

This worked fine (on 16.04 and 17.04, both GNOME) until I upgraded to 17.10. Clicking the shortcut in the dock now opens Tilix **without** my session (i.e. the default behaviour).

When I search for "Tilix" in Activities and click that shortcut, **or** when I navigate to `~/.local/share/applications/` in Nautilus and double-click the `.desktop` file, **Tilix runs with my session as it always has**. It is only when I add the shortcut to favourites that the unwanted behaviour occurs.

What could cause this to happen, and how can I fix it?

---

**Update 1**: Changing the `Exec` line to the absolute path doesn't help, and nor does using a custom shell script.

**Update 2**: I changed the `Exec` line for **both** my custom file (in `~/.local/...`) **and** the original in `/usr/...` to `Exec=gedit`, to see what would happen. Running either file from Nautilus or from search opens Gedit as expected, but **the version in the dock still opens Tilix!** How can it possibly know to do this?

**Update 3**: I added a brand new file: `~/.local/.../com.phydeaux.Tlx.desktop`, identical contents to the above except with `Name=Tlx`. Running this from the dock opens Tilix with my session as desired, so this suffices as a (stupid) workaround. **However**, if I change from `Name=Tlx` to `Name=Tilix`, the unwanted behaviour returns, and persists even if I subsequently change the name back to `Tlx`. Is the shortcut file somehow becoming 'associated' with Tilix-the-application when I do this? Does GNOME think it knows the 'proper' way to run that application? Is any of this to do with D-Bus?

**Update 4**: Still an issue in 18.04. Deleting the service file for Tilix from `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/` doesn't help.

Comment: @pomsky it's the same one that works correctly when I click it

Comment: @pomsky Yep! I've also uninstalled/reinstalled Tilix. No matter what I do, running the shortcut from anywhere other than the dock obeys whatever I put in the `Exec` line (still set to `gedit` currently), whereas running the same shortcut from the dock tries to open Tilix (and does nothing if it isn't installed)

Comment: @pomsky I had a similar-ish problem when I first wrote this file (i.e. `Exec` line being bypassed), but that was resolved by setting `DBusActivatable=false` which obviously isn't helping here

Comment: Please remove "Update 3" from the question and post that as an answer, sounds like a good workaround.

Comment: @pomsky it's not exactly ideal, it (apparently) can't have the proper name, and opens a window under a separate icon in the dock. Not to mention that it doesn't explain **why** this happens. I can post the workaround as an answer, but I won't mark it accepted.

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-icons-in-the-dock-of-gnome-shell-ubuntu-17-10) for double icon issue.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a completely new shortcut file `~/.local/share/applications/com.phydeaux.Tlx.desktop` with identical contents to the original except for `Name=Tlx`, then adding that shortcut to the dock achieves close to the desired behaviour for me.

This successfully opens Tilix with my session, though it opens a window under a different icon in the dock, and appears under a different name (changing the name to `Tilix` causes a relapse to the unwanted behaviour).