# Kile icon buggy in left (launcher) bar (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, kile

Since I upgraded to 18.04  (well, technically, did a clean install), Kile no longer funcitons properly.
More specifically, I added kile to favourites and there is an icon for it in the launcher bar (is that the right name?).
However, when I click it, it opens a window that is bound to some strange "forbidded" icon in my launcher bar
(see image below, the icon under kile is where kile resides when opened).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: strange icon]

---

Update: solved, by following the solution from [Duplicate Icons in the dock of GNOME Shell, Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-icons-in-the-dock-of-gnome-shell-ubuntu-17-10) 
Thanks to    [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky) for pointing this out