# The eclipse icon is replaced with a new one but it is not changed in the Ubuntu dock when I run the app

Tags: icons, eclipse, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I've downloaded the **Eclipse C/C++ IDE for 2018-09** and installed it by extracting the package in a folder. So I've created the following `Eclipse-CDT.desktop` file in `/home/username/.local/share/applications/` to add the eclipse to the gnome menu and the launcher.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse-CDT
Comment=C\C++ IDE
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;
Exec=/home/username/apps/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/home/username/apps/eclipse/icon.xpm
```

I've also changed the `icon.xpm` with the same dimensions. Consequently the`Eclipse-CDT` with the new icon appears in the gnome menu and then we are able to add it to the launcher.

The problem is when I open it from menu or launcher, the former icon(which was removed) is appeared in the launcher as an active app, while the newly added one remains inactive. Why?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I would guess that it's because the entry you have created is only for Desktop as implied at the top of the file by `[Desktop Entry]`.  I'm not sure how to fix this which is what I assume you are trying to ask here.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version and flavour (standard-Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Xubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE etc.)?

Comment: @Jeff Do you mean my question is unclear? @pomsky I'm using `ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate applications icons in Ubuntu dock on Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-applications-icons-in-ubuntu-dock-on-ubuntu-17-10-with-gnome-shell). Your question is fine, you just need to add a correct `StartupWMClass=` line to your `.desktop` file. (cc @Jeff)

Comment: Thanks @pomsky. About the link you shared, I don't understand the concept behind the `WM_CLASS` but the idea that I get from that post was maybe the problem is related to the `name`s. I changed the `.desktop` file name ` and the `Name=` field in it to the `eclips` and the problem solved! The reason? I don't know!

Comment: @mstfyghm Okay, please add what solved the problem as an answer below by clicking the "answer your own question" button to help future readers. It's totally fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the `.desktop` file to the `eclipse.desktop` solved this problem:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications/
mv Eclipse-CDT.desktop eclipse.desktop
```