# Duplicate icons of the same application created on Dock with no WM_class found

Tags: icons, .desktop, ubuntu-dock, recoll, xprop

I followed all the steps in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/975230/719469

However when I run `xprop WM_CLASS` in Terminal and click on my application's window, it gives me: `WM_CLASS:  not found.` What should I do to get a single icon of the app on the Ubuntu Dock?

[image: duplicate icons on Recoll on Launcher]

The application I am talking about is Recoll, installed using `apt-get install recoll`. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (Xorg).

The contents of `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Utility;Filesystem;Database;
Comment=Find documents by specifying search terms
Exec=recoll
GenericName=Local Text Search
Icon=recoll
Name=Recoll
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Keywords=Search;Full Text;
```

**Edit:**

I tried changing the `.desktop` file lines by making these changes

```
Exec=recoll --class CustomClassName
```

and then adding the line

```
StartupWMClass=CustomClassName
```

After doing this, the app fails to launch from its icon and I still get `WM_CLASS:  not found.` in the terminal

Comment: There's [a way to forcefully assign `WM_CLASS`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185440) when it's not found, but I'm not sure how to adapt that to fix your issue.

Comment: @pomsky thanks for sharing the link, the first edit sets a name for a particular window,

`xprop -f WM_CLASS 8s -set WM_CLASS "RecollSearch"`

gives

`WM_CLASS(STRING) = "RecollSearch"`. Edit2 in the answer

`xprop -name "RecollSearch" -f WM_CLASS 8s -set WM_CLASS "CustomName"`

gives

`xprop: error: No window with name RecollSearch exists!`. Thus, on testing on a new window `xprop` gives WM_CLASS not found

Comment: @pomsky I found a similar question with an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396190/8407719) on other networks. But the problem is, as I do not understand scripting, I cannot apply these possibly [working solutions](https://superuser.com/a/1120629) to my problem!

Comment: Might be related to this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118613

Comment: Hope someones provides an answer below for Recoll as it is officially in Ubuntu's Repos and still suffers from this problem

Answer (score 2):

For a similar situation I have to do the following:

1. Determine the class as in the new answer in [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-application-icons-in-ubuntu-dock-upon-launch/#answer-1311202)

   Briefly:

   - open the app
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, write `lg`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, go to `Windows` menu (up-right).
   - find the app in the list and take note of its `wmclass`
   - close lg <kbd>ESC</kbd> and app
2. Add class to `.desktop` file

   ```
   StartupWMClass=classSeenInPreviousStep
   ```

   Normally in: `/usr/share/applications` or `.local/share/applications`
3. keep icon in favorites (add to menu)

   - open app, <kbd>right button</kbd> in icon, 'Add to favorites'.
     If this fails, check that in .desktop `Terminal=false`
   - or: open `dconf-editor`, search `favorite-apps`, add `.desktop` file to list
   - or: Paste this to create a script for that purpose

     ```
     cat >addToMenu.sh <<'EOL'
     #!/usr/bin/env bash
     STATE=`gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`
     STATE=$(sed 's/]/,'\ \'YOURAPP.desktop\'']/g' <<< $STATE)
     gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "${STATE}"
     EOL

     #  Run it:
     sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
     bash addToMenu.sh
     ```

if this fails: Look in the .desktop file for a line with OnlyShowIn=..., and remove the line