# How to make a launcher/desktop app that launches two processes not add items to launcher (dock)?

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

Well considering I have a launch icon, this launches a shell script that (in turn) starts two applications: pgadmin server and a chrome-page opening redirecting to the pgadmin server.

**pgadmin.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=pgadmin
Icon=/home/paul/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.png
Exec=/home/paul/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.sh
```

**shell script**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=ojglidlfoedmhkmjdapihkjneoemohjm &
python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Now this "works". However It also adds two different entries to my launcher, a terminal window, and an entry for the chrome app. It also doesn't give an indication (orange dot) that the original pgadmin application was opened?

(How) Can I make these two applications "combine" in a single entry? (Which is ideally the same as the original launcher icon.

Comment: This should work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-applications-icons-in-ubuntu-dock

Comment: @pomsky that doesn't help at all *combining* the two windows into a single launcher icon. Also the class returned is "gnome-terminal-server", "Gnome-terminal" which is quite generic.