# How to put on favorite .desktop Firefox Develop Edition?

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I've just installed Firefox Developer Edition using the .tar.bz2 on the officiel website. I created the following .desktop to have the shortcut :

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
NoDisplay=false
StartupWMClass=FDE
```

So if I search for "firefox" I have the good Firefox version BUT I couldn't do a right click and "Add to favorite". I could add it to favorite withing Activites, but if I open a window, Firefox add a new entry in the application bar (see screen here :

[image]

How could I do to have the same behaviour as the Messenger application for exemple ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `StartupWMClass=` line have a valid value? See here: https://askubuntu.com/q/975178/480481

Comment: That's ,perfect, thanks a lot ! :) 
`StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition` fix the issue