# Running application associated with wrong .desktop entry

Tags: firefox, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I've got firefox (from apt) and firefox-nightly (from zip) installed at the same time, with two separate desktop entries.

However, when I launch firefox nightly, it's associated with the wrong launcher icon:

[image: launcher icons]

Firefox-nightly has a custom `.desktop` file with the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox -P clean %u
Name=Nightly
Comment=Nightly
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/unknown;x-scheme-handler/about;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/http;text/html
```

How does ubuntu decide which applications are running for the purposes of showing in the dock and how do I fix my `.desktop` entry?

Comment: Can't reproduce, I copied/pasted /usr/share/applcations/firefox.desktop, named firefox-nightly, changed the Exec and Icon accordingly, and it's displayed just fine. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Adding a correct `StartupWMClass` entry to your `.desktop` file should fix it. Please [refer to this](https://askubuntu.com/q/975178/480481) and report back.

Comment: @guillermochamorro It seems this is a wayland issue; it works correctly under X.

Answer (score 1):

Fix seems to be as described here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1585369

E.g.

```
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox --name Nightly -P clean %u
StartupWMClass=Nightly
```