# Where can I find the file format specification for MATE .desktop files?

Tags: mate, .desktop

The title pretty much says it all. I have searched the net; I have munged about in `/usr/share/man/`; I could probably go find the source and take a half day to find what I need but that does not seem reasonable. I am certain I cannot be the only person to have this problem nor will I be the last.

The documentation *must* exist somewhere. I must be using the wrong key words or not grokking the correct name for the man page that tells all about this configuration.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/bin/sh -c "wmctrl -s 1 ; xemacs /home/amon/Desktop/myfile"
Hidden=false
X-MATE-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=emacs myfile
Name=emacs myfile
Comment[en_US]=Always need my basic to do list
Comment=Always need my basic to do list
```

Is there a full syntax definition somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

This is not actually MATE-specific, `.desktop` launchers follow the freedesktop.org standards.

You can find the detailed specification here: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

This is a table containing the standard keys retrieved from the link above:
[image]

Comment: Thank you ever so much. It is a shame they do not put this into a man page as 'desktop-entry-formet' or something like that. I regret that I had to trouble you, but I had failed to find *any* thread or hint that would have led me to this document. So again, thank you for taking the time to assist.

Comment: @DaleAmon If you find this answer useful, please consider ["accepting" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future.