# Pinning LightBurn icon in Ubuntu Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I have installed [LightBurn](https://forum.lightburnsoftware.com/) on Ubuntu. They do not have a full installer for Linux. I run the application by clicking on the `.AppImage` file on my desktop.

While the application is running, the icon appears in the Dock. I want it to stay there when it is closed. When I right click on the LightBurn icon a menu pops-up with:

- ***All Windows >*** (image of LightBurn windows)
- ***Quit***

If I click 'Show Applications', LightBurn does not appears in that list.

How do I get it in the dock?

---

Ubuntu 18.04.3.LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below.

1. Create a `.desktop` file, say `lightburn.desktop`, in `~/.local/share/applications`. You can do that by running the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/lightburn.desktop
   ```
2. Open the `.desktop` file with a text editor of your choice. For example, to open with the default text editor, run

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/shutdown-for-dock.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following lines to the `.desktop` file it and save it.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Short description of the application
   Terminal=false
   Name=LightBurn
   Exec=/full/path/to/the/AppImage-file
   Type=Application
   Icon=/full/path/to/icon/image
   ```
4. Click *Activities* or *Show Applications* and search for "LightBurn". It should appear now.
5. Right click and mark as favourite.
   If right clicking doesn't show an "*Add to favourites*" option, search for the application in *Activities* screen, and then drag it across to the dock.

Comment: Ok got that working. Now when I start the application, I get 2 icons in the Dock. Other applications don't do this. Any way to get that?

Comment: @AlLelopath That should be fixed by adding a proper `StartupWMClass` line in the `.desktop` launcher, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/975178/480481).