# Ubuntu 20.04, appimage in dock adds a new instance upon launch

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-dock, appimage

I got 3 appimage I'd like to launch via the Ubuntu dock on 20.04.
I've manage to add them to the dock, with the correct icons I've downloaded apart.
I'm sure it is possible to find the icon in the appimage, I've to check.

My issue is, when I click on the launcher (which works), the dock adds a new instance of the launcher, so that I've 2 launchers (one is permanent, the one I created and the other is temporary and will be removed when the application is closed).

Is there a mean to avoid the second temporary launcher to be created?
Appimage concerned are CURA, REPETIERHOST, PRUSASLICER, all in last available version.

Comment: You need to add a proper `StartupWMClas` entry to the `.desktop` launchers. Does this answer your question? [Duplicate applications icons in Ubuntu dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-applications-icons-in-ubuntu-dock)

Comment: WORKS GREAT. What i did: launch the app via the dock icon, launch the terminal and type the xprop WMClass, click on the app window once open, add copy the results without the brackets " " into the StartupWMClass of the .destop. Many Thanks POMSKY

Comment: it solves 2 of 3, the last one repetierhost doesn't give results with xprop WMClass it only gives "not found"

Comment: i've added the --class SomeClass and StartupWMClass=SomeClass but i got still the pb

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck. It seems the application itself has a bug. Consider reporting this bug to the application's developer(s).

Comment: i've done xprop only and here is the result:

Comment: WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
  window state: Normal
  icon window: 0x0

Comment: _NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS(CARDINAL) = 170
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 37, 0

Comment: _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Repetier-Host V2.1.6"

Comment: _NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Repetier-Host V2.1.6"
XdndAware(ATOM) = ATOM
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
  Client accepts input or input focus: True
  Initial state is Normal State.
  window id # of group leader: 0x13e
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = 
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x3, 0x3e, 0x7e, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
  user specified location: 77, 60
  program specified location: 77, 60
  program specified minimum size: 632 by 453