# Is it possible to add the option "add to favorite" into a context menu of an Appimage file on 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, menu, appimage, favorites

I wonder if it possible under 20.04, to modify the context menu of a launched appimage application to add "add to favorites" choice?

The complete .desktop which is quite short is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=REPETIERHOST
Comment=SLICER I3MM
Icon=/home/manuh/Documents/AppImages/RepetierHOST_SoftWare.png
Exec=/home/manuh/Documents/AppImages/Repetier-Host-x86_64-2.1.6.AppImage 
Path=/home/manuh/Documents/AppImages
StartupWMClass=Repetier-Host V2.1.6
Actions=
Categories=X-GNOME-Other;
```

Comment: A correct `StartupWMClass` usually does bring the missing 'add to favourites' option, but as [you mentioned before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236071/ubuntu-20-04-appimage-in-dock-adds-a-new-instance-upon-launch#comment2081425_1236071), this specific application has some issue with it.

Comment: i do agree, but i want to know where the possible actions shown in a context menu are defined because depending on the launcher the actions are not the same. THere should be somewhere to define and maybe modify those actions or am I wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this specific action (add to favourites) is *not* app specific, GNOME Shell provides it upon detecting a valid launcher. From my experience, it fails to provide this action when the `StartupWMClass` entry is not a valid one.