# Duplicated dock icons on Ubuntu 20.04 when I unlock the screen

Tags: 20.04, icons, ubuntu-dock, unlock

When I unlock the screen on my Ubuntu 20.04, every app icon is duplicated(picture link below)

My extension: Dash to Dock

My customisation:

- Theme: Adapta-Cyan-Nokto-Eta
- Icons: OieIcons

I use tweaks

Ubuntu 20.04 dock

[image]

I did some research(this link below): 
https://askubuntu.com/a/975230/1109086

But still the same thing. It happens only when I unlock the screen; when I reboot the laptop or log out and log in again, the docks are not duplicated.

Comment: From the screenshot, clearly not a default desktop. Mention customizations you have done, including extensions you may have installed (use "edit" to add relevant information to your question)

Answer (score 0):

Search "extension" open it
and close Ubuntu Dock from there.

[image: search Extensionclose ubuntu dock##]

Comment: could you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: I think you wanted to say something what I edited?