# How can I make a custom desktop file for VS Code for my dock, under Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, .desktop, visual-studio-code

I want to make a launcher icon on the dock for VSCode under Ubuntu 20.04. I called it `code.desktop` and put it in `.local/share/applications`, then pinned it to the dock. However, when I click on it, I get two icons:

[image]

The desktop file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=code
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
NoDisplay=false
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/snap/bin/code
Icon=/snap/code/49/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=code
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;application/x-code-workspace;
Keywords=vscode;
```

What gives? I tried the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-application-icons-in-ubuntu-dock-upon-launch) but they seem to be either obsolete or not applicable to VS Code somehow. `wmprop` gives me `"code", "Code"` for the WMClass, and as you can see I've already set that as the `StartupWMClass` (and the filename of the desktop file, as someone else recommended at that link).

Answer (score 0):

I have no real idea why, but I solved this by renaming my `code.desktop` to `code_code.desktop`.