# Click on Ubuntu 21.04 icons (left navigation) opens new icon rather than adding a red dot

Tags: xorg, icons, wayland, navigation, kile

My OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

Note that I do not use the `Wayland` display server protocol that's used by default by Ubuntu 21.04. Since this is apparently buggy in the current version I had to switch back `Xorg`. How that's done is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352062/xte-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-21-04).

In Ubuntu's navigation on the left every new instance of a program is indicated by another red bullet next to it, so the number of bullets tells how many instances are open. In case of thunderbird, for example, every new email window also gets another dot. For some programs (like kile, but also others) that does however not seem to work as shown here:

[image: bug for kile]

You can see that the kile program icon (in blue) which is part of the navigation -- and onto which I clicked to open it! -- does not show any red bullets. Instead it opens another instance (which correctly gets the red dot), and this one uses a default icon. Clearly that's a bug/wrong! How can this be resolved? As said, this behavior is not specific to kile, it also happens with others.

Please also note that this seems (extremely) closely related to the following [StackOverflow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347617/ubuntu-21-04-custom-firefox-desktop-creates-new-icon-rather-than-run-indicator-b) post, though that one also does not have any answer (and although it's also in Ubuntu 21.04, it seems to still use Wayland). I do not regard it a duplicate, since there are differences: That post talks about this phenomenon when creating a new starter on the desktop, which is not what I did. I just click on the correct icon in the navigation. (And as said: I deactivated Wayland, which the other user apparently didn't.)

What's causing that and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What's typically causing it is either the .desktop file provided by the package or the image that the .desktop file points to. It's fairly easy for you to fix for yourself once you check those tow items. If you discover the details of the problem, be sure to file a proper bug report so you can get it fixed for everybody.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Once I found time to look into what you said and I fixed it I'll post an official bug report as suggested (on top of answering the question here and the one I linked).

Comment: I think I have to bail.^^ I've checked out the kile.desktop in /usr/share/applications -- but I don't see what should be wrong with it. There's a line Icon=Kile, but I can't tell whether this is right since I've no clue how my OS knows what that means, i.e., where to look for this file called "Kile". Any idea?

Comment: Furthermore, I think there are actually two issues: one is that the new instance of the program has a wrong symbol, and the other one is that it opens a new instance instead of just putting a red dot next to it. So I'm pretty much clueless what to look for in that regard. One idea: I'm not sure but it could be that opening a new instance happens for exactly those entries which I added via alacarte (but not sure).

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: here the file:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=kile %U
Icon=/home/ProfChaos/icons/Kile.svg
X-DocPath=kile/index.html
Comment=(La)TeX development environment
Terminal=false
Name=Kile
GenericName=LaTeX Frontend
MimeType=text/x-tex;text/x-kilepr;
Categories=Qt;KDE;Office;Publishing;
X-DBUS-ServiceName=net.sourceforge.kile
(Just to be save I've replaced the symbol with an absolute path to an existing file.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the `xprop` tool if you don't have it.

   ```
   sudo apt install x11-utils
   ```
2. Get the WM Class of your Kile application.

   Launch Kile.

   Open a terminal, and execute the following:

   ```
   xprop | grep WM_CLASS
   ```

   The cursor will change to a cross ("+") shape. Click on the headerbar of your Kile window with this cursor.

   In the terminal, y ou will see an output like:

   ```
   WM_CLASS(STRING) = ...
   ```

   Note this value.
3. Update your `*.desktop` file.

   In the terminal, execute:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/applications/org.kde.kile.desktop
   ```

   Scroll to the end of the file, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add a new line, and type the following. Replace `<WM_CLASS>` with the value you noted from step 2.

   ```
   StartupWMClass=<WM_CLASS>
   ```

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save your changes and exit the Nano editor.

Now, when you launch Kile, you will see one icon in the dock (multiple) indicators for running instances.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I realized that this is actually a [duplicate of this question about duplicate items](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975178/duplicate-application-icons-in-ubuntu-dock-upon-launch).

Well, I don't need to say much because the solution provided by `pomsky` is absolutely perfect! Just follow his detailed step-by-step instruction and everything works. :)

(Let me know in the comments if you believe that I should copy his instruction in here again.)

Comment: (I just flagged my question as a duplicate.)