# How can I add a link to a folder / hard drive to the Ubuntu dock?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I would like to add drives and folders to the *Favorites* sidebar in Ubuntu 18.04 (I mean the Dock, in Nautilus <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is working fine). Drag and drop doesn't work - this seems unintuitive.

Is there a way without using the terminal?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it can be done *without using the terminal*, see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966740/how-do-i-pin-my-favorite-folders-in-ubuntu-dock-like-in-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without terminal, but by using a modified* version of [pomksy](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky)'s answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966740/how-do-i-pin-my-favorite-folders-in-ubuntu-dock-like-in-windows) question, I got what I wanted:

1. creating and opening a desktop file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/hd1.desktop
   ```
2. adding nautilus file explorer with the location:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=hd1
   Exec=nautilus /media/username/hd1
   Icon=drive-harddisk
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
   ```
3. search for "hd1" in dash, find it, rightclick and "add to favorites".

* modified, because it's leftclick - and a different Icon.