# How do I pin a file shortcut to Ubuntu dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, shortcuts, ubuntu-dock, dock

I would like to pin a file's shortcut to the dock in the Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME desktop so that the file opens directly when I click it, for example a spreadsheet file that opens with LibreOffice Calc. Is this possible?

Comment: You can pin only Application to Gnome Dock.. But you can found some similar solution in this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966740/how-do-i-pin-my-favorite-folders-in-ubuntu-dock-like-in-windows

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Follow the steps below.

1. Create a `.desktop` file (say `spreadsheet1.desktop`) in `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. You can do that by running the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/spreadsheet1.desktop
   ```
2. Open the file with a text editor, for example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/spreadsheet1.desktop
   ```

   Then add the following lines:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=XYZ spreadsheet
   Exec=xdg-open /full/path/to/XYZ-spreadsheet.ods
   Comment=Launch XYZ spreadsheet
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=x-office-spreadsheet
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. Click on "*Activities*" or "*Show Applications*" and search for "XYZ spreadsheet". It should appear.
5. Right click on it and mark as favourite.

**Note:** The `xdg-open` command opens the file with the default application associated with the file-type. You can alternatively set

```
Exec=libreoffice /full/path/to/XYZ-spreadsheet.ods
```

in the `.desktop` file to always open the file with LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer from @pomsky, if you want to change the icon, refer to [this page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Desktop_icons).

For example, if you click the icon and the referred url is

`https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Desktop_icons#/media/File:Gnome-emblem-favorite.svg`,

then replace the `Icon` value with `emblem-favorite`.