# pin folders in dock in 20-04

Tags: gnome, nautilus, files, dock

Alex Goes Fuhrmann and Pomsky have described the process to pin folders to the files icon on the Ubuntu dock in 18.04 ([How do I pin my favorite folders in Ubuntu dock like in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966740/how-do-i-pin-my-favorite-folders-in-ubuntu-dock-like-in-windows/1118780#1118780)). I had this working in 18.04, but it no longer applies in 20.04.

In 20.04, there are 2 files related to nautilus in */usr/share/applications*: *naultilus-autorun-software.desktop* and *org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop*. The latter is very similar to nautilus.desktop.

So I followed the same procedure (copy *org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop* to *~/.local/share/applications*, edit the "Actions=" line and add "[Desktop-Action ...]" sections). Now, while the new locations are listed under the files icon, only the first (--new-window) does anything.

What is wrong, or missing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in vandium's answer to this question: [How do I add new locations to right-click menu of “Files” launcher in Ubuntu dock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180311/how-do-i-add-new-locations-to-right-click-menu-of-files-launcher-in-ubuntu-doc)

A new version of *org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop* in *~/.local/share/applications* is the right way to go, but as vanadium included, change the dbus line to read

```
DBusActivatable=false
```

Thanks [vanadium](/questions/tagged/vanadium).