# Ubuntu 20.04 Nautilus Quicklist / Jumplist

Tags: 20.04, menu

On Ubuntu 18.04 I created a nautilus.desktop file, so that a right click on the starter opened a [jump- or quicklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL6pE.png)

the entries looked something like that:

```
[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=nautilus --new-window
[Desktop Action NewShortcut]
Name= --
Exec=-
[Desktop Action NewShortcut1]
Name=Persönlicher Ordner
Exec=nautilus /home/ck
```

After a fresh install with Ubuntu 20.04 this does not seem to work any more, using the old starter does not create the jump- or quicklist. Basically nothing happens. Any ideas how to acieve a jump- or quicklist?

Thx, k

Answer (score 1):

It still works almost the same way. 
You just have to set:

```
DBusActivatable=false
```

See [How do I add new locations to right-click menu of “Files” launcher in Ubuntu dock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180311/how-do-i-add-new-locations-to-right-click-menu-of-files-launcher-in-ubuntu-doc)