# How do you pin elements per favorite in Ubuntu dock?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, dock

I've recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and noticed that you can't pin different elements per favorite in Ubuntu dock, like in Windows. For example, pin certain folders to "Files" favorite, pin many workspaces to "VS Code" favorite, pin many workspaces to "Postman" favorite, etc. I found a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966740/) but it's directed only at pinning folders to Files, not other apps.

Is there any way to do this in Ubuntu without having to edit files? The ideal situation would be to be able to pin it directly from "Open Windows" list. I'm open to installing new programs or extensions.

Comment: Check out these articles - https://averagelinuxuser.com/ubuntu_custom_launcher_dock/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-apps-favorites.html.en .
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to edit files, but editing text files is the only way to add custom right-click menu items to an icon in the dock.

Another dock application, **Plank**, will also use these same right-menu items. However, with that dock, you can create icons on the dock that represent groups of apps

[image]

There are many references on how to use Plank dock, among others [A Guide To Using Plank Dock](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/12/a-guide-to-using-plank-dock-on-linux.html). You will then want to [disable the default Ubuntu dock](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232743/558158). [Here](https://www.fosslinux.com/478/how-to-add-folders-and-group-apps-to-the-plank-in-elementary-os.htm) you can learn how to add folders and group apps to the dock.