# How can I get an app listed into Dash

Tags: software-installation, unity-dash, appmenu

Sorry for the silly question, but I wonder how can I get an app I built (with cmake) listed in the dash.
Immediately after the build completed, I moved into a /usr/lib/folder brand new folder.
I thought that would have sufficed, but that's not the case.

I have read several posts about problems with Dash, but they all make reference to rebuilding because of potential problems.
I could give them a go, but I'm not sure in first instance a simple file move is enough.

Any guidance?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a `.desktop` file in `/usd/share/applications`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any built in tool to do it, or should i clone a file an fill in details?

Comment: You do not need a tool to create a text file. You can do it in any editor.

Comment: @AndreaMoro Did you mean [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash)?

Comment: Thanks  that did the trick in seconds. @Pilot6 yes I was on the same page, but I didn't know whether there were some tool available by default.