# Desktop Icon to Youtube Video?

Tags: firefox, video, icons, shortcuts, ubuntu-gnome

It's close to Christmas and I find myself often displaying a virtual fireplace on my TV used as screen for Ubuntu Gnome.

Is it possible to create a desktop link that will open a new window in, say, Firefox, and start playing the video?

**Bonus question:** Is it possible to 1) turn annotations off, 2) loop the video, and 3) go full screen?

Comment: Just as idea - how about downloading the video once (i.e. using youtube-dl - example: `yoututbe-dl -t https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCp1_XQbiwc) and then run it locally in a player like mplayer or vlc (both come with fullscreen and repeat functions). Should save bandwidth and work as well if your internet is down.

Comment: VLC should support both `--loop` and  `--fullscreen` as commandline parameters which could be handy for a script.

Comment: If you don't care about data usage, I believe you could just drag the URL icon to the desktop and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pre: Optional

Download your movie to have an offline solution. `youtube-dl` is one of several tools which allow downloading videos from Youtube.

Example:

```
youtube -t https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCp1_XQbiwc
```

Package requirements:

```
youtube-dl
```

## Main Task - Bash-Script

Create a new textfile `fire.sh`, make it executable via `chmod +x fire.sh` and insert the following

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# offline version:
MOVIE_PATH="${HOME}/path/to/local/youtube/movie.extension"
#
# online version:
#MOVIE_PATH="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCp1_XQbiwc"
#
# start video using vlc
/usr/bin/vlc --loop --fullscreen "$MOVIE_PATH"
```

Package requirements:

```
vlc
```

**Keep in mind:**

- There is no real need in moving this commandline call to a script,
  while i stilll prefer it as you might want to pimp it overtime (.i.e.
  picking a random clip from a selection or whatever else).
- `vlc` should be replaceable with `mplayer` for example, while you would need to check the needed parameters for loop and fullscreen.

## Post: Optional

In case you really need or want a dash icon to start this script consider checking out the package `alacarte` - while double-clicking the `fire.sh` in your fileexplorer (assuming nautilus) should offer an execute dialog as well.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!
A small detail: I do prefer this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiqM3lVirkw over the one you chose, but how could you have know? ;) Glædelig Jul!

Comment: @rasmus hehe - mine was a random searchresult.

Answer (score 2):

The idea in the comment from @dufte is the best one for your purpose.

You can then create a **desktop entry** with the command :

```
vlc --loop  --fullscreen /path/to/your/video.avi
```

You can also search for other options from on the [VideoLAN forum](https://forum.videolan.org/)  to suit your needs

To create such a desktop entry you can go to [that page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash) to see how to make one.

I think the method described with alacarte will allow you to easily do that

Comment: I did not add enough rep to add comment to tell him about creating a desktop entry

Comment: @patrick-negus Plus I clearly stated that his answer was good and then added my part. And we're just here to help so there nothing such as 'stealing'

Comment: @Patrick as weird as it is, AU allows anyone to take an answer from the comments. Attribution or a "hey, make this an answer" is a nice gesture, but not at all necessary. This is to discourage making answers in the comment section. Please remove your downvote if that was you.

Comment: no problem from my point of view, its all about offering solutions / help.

Comment: @PatrickNegus that's fine, but this answer isn't deserving of a downvote for your reason.