# Add AppImage to Applications menu (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, appmenu, appimage

I have downloaded an AppImage (Balena Etcher). It works fine and I want to add it to the 'Show Applications' menu so that I don't have to navigate to its folder each time I want to use it. I have tried right-clicking both the file and icon in the dock but I can't find an option to do it. Is this possible?

Comment: Try this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash or this post https://superuser.com/questions/1282203/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-to-the-show-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a solid and extensive answer read this: https://askubuntu.com/a/112812/1024353, for a minimal working example, continue reading.

Besides the `Exec`, you should also add a `Name` and `Type` field to your `.destop` file. These fields are required by the [desktop entry spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys).

So your minimal `.desktop` file could look like this:

```
Exec=/path/to/AppImage
Name=AppImageLauncher
Type=Application
```

I'll assume from this point that you named your file `myappimage.desktop` and placed it in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Note that putting this `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` is probably more appropriate than in `/usr/share/applications` in this case, because you won't require root access.

Now make it executable:

```
chmod 700 ~/.local/share/applications/myappimage.desktop
```

I did not have to re-login to make it show up in the menu, but your milage may vary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does the job, but unfortunately it does not display the icon. All apps are displayed with gray system gear icon.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [desktop entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_entries) with the `Exec` parameter as follows:

```
Exec=/path/to/AppImage
```

Save the file with a `.desktop` extension, and make it **executable** like so:

```
sudo chmod u+x /path/to/MyApp.desktop
```

Then just copy/move this desktop file to the `/usr/share/applications` folder, perhaps through the terminal like so:

```
sudo mv /path/to/MyApp.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

Logout and login again to your desktop environment if needed and you'll now see the app in the Applications menu.

Note, however, that this app will not show up in the `Open with Application` context menu list (at least doesn't on Arch Linux).