# Cannot start AppImage on GNOME Desktop, but able to run with command line

Tags: 20.04, gnome, appimage

I recently found that I cannot start AppImage when using GNOME with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. None of double clicking and <kbd>right-click</kbd> → *Open* worked.

I changed the file's permissions to `777` and also made it executable, but it just doesn't work.However, running from command line was a very smooth deal.

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to <kbd>right-click</kbd> it and select *Run*.

If you want to add your AppImage to your applications menu or launchers, check out [melvio's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1356674/618353) on this question: [Add AppImage to Applications menu (20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278640/add-appimage-to-applications-menu-20-04)